# Remove bottom left hover from bing maps

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

[image: Highlighted area]

When implementing a bing maps based solution, the logo on the bottom left (highlighted in image above) causes a search box to appear to search with bing. Has anyone been successful in disabling this feature?

Ideally the solution will not involve disabling hovering events on the map completely, as there are hover events that we have implemented to provide functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When initialising the map, set the *enableSearchLogo* property to False.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427603.aspx

Comment: Works perfectly. Didn't think to look in mapOptions.